# Making nested selector to generate selector without space

Tags: css, less

I have a certain scenario in Less that I would like to write in more simple way.

I have this html:

```
<div class="parent selector-one selector-two">
    Parent
    <div class="child">
        Child
    </div>
    <div class="second-child">
        Second child
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to generate this css by less:

```
.parent {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.parent.selector-one {
    color green;
}

.parent.selector-two .child {
    color: red;
}

.parent .second-child {
    color: blue;
}
```

I would like to write something like this in Less:

```
.parent {
    #SYNTAX#:selector-one {
        color:green;
    }

    #SYNTAX#:selector-two {
        &.child {
            color:red;
        }
    }

    &.second-child {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Is there any syntax to do something like this in Less?

Comment: you have to write it in sccs file and NOT css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should do the job.

As the `&` selects the parent element.

```css
.parent {
    &.selector-one {
        color:green;
    }

    &.selector-two {
        .child {
            color:red;
        }
    }

    & .second-child {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```